# Command-line SSH/SCP client command for windows (not cygwin)

Tags: windows, ssh, command-line

I'm looking for a very basic OpenSSH client for Windows. It should be 100% command-line so that I may run it from Console2. The only stipulation is that it should not be Cygwin-based. If possible, I would expect the command to look identical to how it is on *nix environments.

Example:

```
ssh username@server.host
scp myfile.txt username@server.host:~
```

Some rationale for my criteria:

1. I have Console2 configured how I like it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> for paste, etc).
2. I have UnxUtils added to my environment and SSH/SCP is a natural extension of that.
3. I have very simple bash scripts that would automatically translate into .BAT format with the addition of these commands.
4. Cygwin makes too many fundamental changes to the environment and certain Windows-centric tasks cannot easily be migrated to this environment, and I prefer to follow a standard approach for everything.

Comment: AFAIK *putty* can do that: `putty.exe -ssh username@server.host` to open an SSH session, and `pscp.exe` for the SCP part.

Comment: @Izzy That should be an answer instead, it fulfills the requirements :D. In addition, Putty provides a 100% based console version (plink.exe).

Comment: Putty has poor encryption support though and would force your server to use weaker encryption to be compatible.

Comment: @Tanath do you have documentation to back that up?

Comment: Did you try looking it up? It hasn't supported chacha20-poly1305 or curve25519, but looks like they added them recently in current snapshots (should be coming to 0.67 then): http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/
It also only generates weaker keys, using RSA & DSA.

Answer (score 3):

**[PuTTY](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY)** can do that. While its GUI is relatively well-known, it also offers a command-line: you can use `plink` to initiate an SSH session, and `pscp` to copy files over SSH/SCP. Without any parameters given, they will show you a short help screen with available options. Their basic use is similar to OpenSSH:

```
# copy files via SCP
pscp fred@example.com:/etc/hosts c:\temp\example-hosts.txt
pscp c:\documents\foo.txt fred@example.com:/tmp/foo

# Login to a remote server
plink -ssh login.example.com
plink root@myserver
```

*PuTTY* is the quasi-standard for this on Windows and thus has been forked multiple times. It's known to be reliable and stable.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 12/2017:**

OpenSSH client and server is shipped with latest Windows 10 update so you do not need any of this, just update your system and you will have OpenSSH installed:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/12/15/using-the-openssh-beta-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-and-windows-server-1709/

OpenSSH has been recently ported to Windows by PowerShell team. It is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH). The installation is pretty straight-forward and most of the things work as on *nix.

Comment: That looks more like an SSH server, not a client.

Comment: it is openssh, so it is both. You don't have to run the server part.

Comment: Looks like it requires Cygwin? https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/OpenSSH-64-bit-Build-and-Installation-Instructions

Comment: So my bad. I was hoping that MS was able to achieve something more than is available already.

Comment: @JamesWatkins [No longer](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH). The page you sourced is outdated now.